# How to parallelize A* algorithm using Open MP?

Tags: c++, c++11, parallel-processing, openmp

I am having trouble parallelizing A* algotithm. I have tried parallelizing individual for loops but that didn't improve anything. In fact serial implementation is still faster than this one. Can you help me improve this or give me some ideas?

```
while(openSet.size() > 0){
    PAIR current = {};
    int maxVal = INT32_MAX;

    int i;
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(tc) ordered schedule(dynamic, 1) private(i) shared(openSet, maxVal, current, fScores)
    for(i = 0;i < openSet.size();i++){
        if(fScores[openSet[i].x * dim + openSet[i].y] < maxVal){
            #pragma omp ordered
            maxVal = fScores[openSet[i].x * dim + openSet[i].y];
            current = openSet[i];
        }
    }

    if(current.x == xEnd && current.y == yEnd){
        elapsed = omp_get_wtime() - start;
        //printMat(gScores, dim);
        printPath("res.txt", mat, cameFrom, current, dim, tc);
        break;
    }

    int rm = check_remove(openSet, current, tc);
    openSet.erase(openSet.begin() + rm);

    vector<PAIR> neighbours;

    if(current.x - 1 >= 0 && mat[(current.x - 1) * dim + current.y] != '1'){
        neighbours.push_back(PAIR(current.x - 1, current.y));
    }
    if (current.y - 1 >= 0 && mat[current.x * dim + (current.y - 1)] != '1'){
        neighbours.push_back(PAIR(current.x, current.y - 1));
    }
    if (current.x + 1 < dim && mat[(current.x + 1) * dim + current.y] != '1'){
        neighbours.push_back(PAIR(current.x + 1, current.y));
    }
    if (current.y + 1 < dim && mat[current.x * dim + (current.y + 1)] != '1'){
        neighbours.push_back(PAIR(current.x, current.y + 1));
    }
    
    int tentative_gScore;
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(tc) ordered schedule(dynamic, 1) private(i) shared(neighbours, openSet, gScores, fScores, tentative_gScore)
    for(i = 0;i < neighbours.size();i++){
        tentative_gScore = gScores[current.x * dim + current.y] + 1;

        if(tentative_gScore < gScores[neighbours[i].x * dim + neighbours[i].y]){
            #pragma omp ordered
            cameFrom[neighbours[i].x * dim + neighbours[i].y] = current;
            gScores[neighbours[i].x * dim + neighbours[i].y] = tentative_gScore;
            fScores[neighbours[i].x * dim + neighbours[i].y] = tentative_gScore + hScore(); //(p.x, p.y, xEnd, yEnd)
            if(contains(openSet, neighbours[i]) == false){
                openSet.push_back(neighbours[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A* is not a good candidate for parallelization. But you could use better data structures to make it faster.

Comment: I used vectors. What do you suggest i use?

Comment: A* is a best-first search, meaning nodes are intended to be processed in a certain order (best-first). This makes it essentially impossible to parallelize.

Comment: @IgorKaradzic [a combination of a heap and hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41297236/555045) for the open set. I don't see any closed set in your code, but also something indexable for that, not something that requires a full search

Comment: Will try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop, the `ordered` clause induces a huge waste of time that you can avoid by using `reduction` if you need only `maxVal`. However, since you need also `current` you have to do the reduction manually. So, instead of looking for `maxVal` and `current` directly, you should create intermediate vectors for these variables , namely `maxValVector` and `currentVector`. Then, I suggests that each thread looks for `maxValVector[omp_get_thread_num()]` and `currentVector[omp_get_thread_num()]`. Thus, you don't need to use `ordered` clause and each thread knows the maximum encountred value. Then, you look, using a serial mini loop on the number of threads involved, to get `maxVal` and `current` from `maxValVector` and `currentVector`. This should allow you to have a more efficient parallelization for the first loop.

In the second loop, the variable `tentative_gScore` should be private in order to garantee thread safe. Also I don't see the need of `ordered` clause here too. Not sure what is going with `openSet.push_back(neighbours[i]);`, but probably this line should be protected by `atomic`, if possible, or `critical` clause.